# Cannot build PDF on Editorial Manager

Tags: compiling

I have a TeX manuscript I would like to upload through the "**[Editorial Manager](https://www.editorialmanager.com/)**" platform.

However, I keep getting errors like this when the platform tries to build the manuscript :

[image: Compilation Errors]

I uploaded a **zip** folder containing these files :

[image: Uploaded Files]

The **JounalPics** folder contains the figures all in **.png**

I wrote the manuscript using KILE and it compiles correctly. I get the compilation errors when uploading to [Editorial Manager](https://www.editorialmanager.com/).

What did I do wrong ? And how can I fix it ?

**Edit :**

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rff13ss58woyu8i/article.log?dl=0) is the `log` file .

Comment: The linked log file doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @JosephWright The TEX compiles fine on my machine, but when I upload it to `Editorial Manager`, the generated PDF has 40 pages displaying things like what you have on that picture

Comment: that is the log file not the typeset output (see the `.log` on your local version), I have no idea what editorial manager is, but it's showing you the wrong thing.

Comment: What is `the "Editorial Manager"`? It is possible few or no others know what this is.

Comment: @jon the `Editorial Manager` is a plateform used by journals in order to submit papers https://www.editorialmanager.com/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the log I placed on dropbox is the `.log` on my local version. After uploading the TEX and the related files on the `Editorial Manager` plateform https://www.editorialmanager.com/ , as required from the journal I'm trying to submit to, the generated PDF gave me 40 pages of what you're seeing in the picture

Comment: You have, at line 311, `It is important to mention that α                                         represnts the links’ hardness.` It should be `It is important to mention that $\alpha$ represents the links’ hardness.` (fix also the typo). I believe you get the same error on all TeX distributions, the only difference is that on your system you disregarded it.

Comment: @egreg I suspect that the OP believes that by using UTF-8 encoded files all their UTF8 symbols would show up on the produced PDF file. You are right in pointing out that's a mistake, at least as PDFLaTeX is concerned. Should we recommend using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead? As for the OP's system, it is likely that KILE executes PDFLaTeX in nonstop mode, so the error is ignored and the PDF produced simply omits the α.

Comment: sorry I scrolled over the log too quickly I expected errors to be at the end but you made tex continue after the error, `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char α (U+3B1)` is in your dropbox

Comment: @erreka now that you mentioned it, I did get `PDFLatex finished with exit code 1` message, yet I still got my PDF generated. Now that I have corrected the `$\alpha$` issue, I don't have that message anymore.

Comment: user1885868: better follow egreg's advice and use LaTeX commands for your symbols, at least in projects you mean to send through your platform: I don't know if they allow you to choose engines, as ShareLaTeX or Overleaf do; so better stick to the basic functionality of PDFLaTeX, which should be upwards compatible with "modern" TeXes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char α (U+3B1)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.311 It is important to mention that α
                                         represnts the links’ hardness. Th...

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

This means that at line 311 of your TeX file you have

```
It is important to mention that α represnts the links’ hardness.
```

which should be

```
It is important to mention that $\alpha$ represents the links’ hardness.
```

The same error is probably present in the log file you get on your system. Always check for errors after a LaTeX run, every front-end will tell you if there has been any.